# How can i check range between all value in columns

Tags: python, mysql

Given bellow my MYSQL table. The value fixed:

```
Fuel           Percentage(%)
------         -------
150 (L)          100 
120 (L)          90 
90  (L)          70
10  (l)          20
```

This data also fixed. Suppose i declare variable getValue= 130
Now i want to check the getValue=130 is which range in MYSQL table.
Its easily guessable that getValue=130 range will be (120 L to 150 L) and percentage range is (90 to 100)
So in this problem statement. How can i find range and find percentage of MYSQL database table ?
how can i do this using python.

Comment: What happens to cases out of the range? For example for value `5` or value `200`?

Comment: I can't understand your comment sir. Actually i want to find ratio based on the range that already i mentioned in my question :)

Comment: MySQL 5.x or MySQL 8.x?

Comment: I used mysql 8.x right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are always retrieving values in a valid range (i.e. between 10 and 150 in your example) the following query gives you the range:

```
select
  f.fuel as fuel_from, f.percentage as percentage_from,
  t.fuel as fuel_to, t.percentage as percentage_to
from (
  select * from t where fuel <= 130 order by fuel desc limit 1
) f
cross join (
  select * from t where fuel >= 130 order by fuel limit 1
) t
```